# Translate NT format (NetBIOS) Domain name to Distinguished Name (DNS Domain Name)

Tags: powershell, dns, netbios

I'm currently using the below code to convert NT format (NetBIOS) domain names to Distinguished name (DNS Domain name).

`NameTranslate` object works great in my code... until I try to use the same code over my work VPN... resulting in an exception

> The remote procedure call failed. (HRESULT: 0x800706BE)

I'm looking for an alternate way to do this (any way at all in a PowerShell script without having problems over VPN).  I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require 3rd party PS modules or assembly dependencies, with the fewest lines of code.

```PoS
$Domain = "SF"
$objTrans = New-Object -comObject "NameTranslate"
$objNT = $objTrans.GetType()
$objNT.InvokeMember("Init", "InvokeMethod", $Null, $objTrans, (3, $Null))
$objNT.InvokeMember("Set", "InvokeMethod", $Null, $objTrans, (3, "$Domain\"))
$DNSDomain = $objNT.InvokeMember("Get", "InvokeMethod", $Null, $objTrans, 1)
```

**EDIT:**  For those who don't have much experience with NameTranslate (and also need a bigger picture what I'm trying to do):

I need to validate user-input'ed AD username/password, e.g., '**SF\MKANET**' for the username.  The best way I know to validate an AD account in PowerShell is with the below code.  I need a programmatic way to take the "SF" this user-inputed text example; and, convert it to a format that can be used where **$DNSDomain** goes below.  If someone has alternate solution with I could use to do the same thing, please let me know.

```PoS
$DOM = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry($DNSDomain,$UserName,$Password)
if ($DOM.name -ne $null) {$CredentialValid = $True}
```

Comment: Give an example of what your start product and end product are.  For people that don't have familiarity with that really specific library, your code example isn't helpful.

Comment: What problem are you solving by converting names between formats in this way?

Comment: I update my original post to be as clear as possible what I need to accomplish.  Hopefully, a brilliant person can provide a usable solution.